# Android NDK link time

Tags: android, gcc, makefile, android-ndk

My application uses one big precompiled static library, and the linking stage takes a very long time (1 minute).
I tried to make this library dynamic, but it still takes 1 minute.

Right now the only thing I have in mind is to write a wrapper library, which will export only those methods I need. But I really don't want to do that, so is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone will encounter the same problem (slow ld), the solution is to use gold linker.